# How to create an iterator method that iterates starting at a specific position

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

I am writing a function called `public Iterator<E> iterator(int index)` that returns an iterator starting at the specified position ('index') in the list.  The specified index is 0-based.  My code so far is below.

```
public Iterator<E> iterator(int index) {
      Iterator<E> it = iterator(index);
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            E item = it.next();
            System.out.println(item);

        }
      return it;
  }
```

The code in main looks like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      LinkedList<Integer> lst = new LinkedList<Integer>();

      lst.add(3);
      lst.append(6);
      lst.append(5);
      lst.append(7);

      lst.iterator(1);
```

lst is a linked list.  When I try to call the iterator method on it passing in 1, I expect it to iterate through the linked list starting at position 1, which should then print:  `6 5 7`.

However, instead, I get an error message which reads

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Midterm.LinkedList.iterator(LinkedList.java:183)
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  My question is, can anybody show me how to fix my `public Iterator<E> iterator(int index)` method so that iterates through the linked list starting at position 1?

Comment: `iterator(int)` calls `iterator(int)` on its first line.

Comment: ... which results in endless recursion

Comment: You're getting a `StackOverflowError` because `iterator` calls itself. Are you writing your own LinkedList class or extending the standard one?

Comment: Notwithstanding the StackOverflowError, the returned iterator would have no elements, because the while loop would only finish when `it.hasNext()` is false.

Comment: Ah, understood, this explains it.  Thanks everybody.  @PaulBoddington, I am extending the standard one.

Comment: If you're extending the standard one why do you need to override iterator()?

Comment: You just need to call the method something else and it will work.

Comment: @PaulBoddington, sorry, I misread your question.  I am not extending the standard linked list class.  I am writing my own.

Comment: Well in that case you need to show all your code so far. Personally, I'd accept Pinkie Swirl's answer and ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call your method recursively without ever stopping:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator(int index) {
    Iterator<E> it = iterator(index); // calls this method again
```

So it will just call `iterator(int index) -> iterator(int index) -> iterator(int index) -> ...` indefinitely.

This will cause a stack overflow, since the stack has a limited size.

Comment: loop wasn't the right word, it is a never stopping recursive call (no English native speaker here, so sorry if there is a term for that).

Comment: I've heard it called *infinite recursion*.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get my iterator method to return an iterator that started at the index variable location with the following code.

```
public Iterator<E> iterator(int index) {
    Iterator<E> iterator = iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < index && iterator.hasNext(); i++) {
        iterator.next();
    }
    return iterator;
}
```